# Yii2 GridView implement Filter and Sort for Values for related Table of foreign Table

Tags: gridview, yii2, crud, gii

I have 3 Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tabCve
(
    intCveID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    strNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    fltScore FLOAT(0),
    strDescription TEXT,
    datImported DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    intCvePhaseID INTEGER,
    intCveTypeID INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (intCveID),
    KEY (intCvePhaseID),
    KEY (intCveTypeID)

) ;


CREATE TABLE tabProgress
(
    intProgressID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    intProgressCveID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    intProgressUserID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    intProgressStateID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    intProgressCategoryID INTEGER,
    datCreated DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intProgressID),
    KEY (intProgressCategoryID),
    KEY (intProgressCveID),
    KEY (intProgressStateID),
    KEY (intProgressUserID)

) ;

CREATE TABLE tabCategory
(
    intCategoryID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    strCategory VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (intCategoryID)

) ;
```

I have created a CRUD with Gii for `tabCve`.
I was successfull in implementing filter and sort functions for fields in referenced tables like `intCvePhaseID`

Now I would like to implement this for `tabCategory` via `tabProgress`
the relation between `tabCve` and `tabProgress` is 1 to 1.

How do I have to implement it in my SearchModel?

**What I did so far:**

In the Model:

```
public function getProgress()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TabProgress::className(),['intProgressCveID' => 'intCveID'])->with(['category']);
}   

public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TabCategory::className(),['intCategoryID' => 'intProgressCategoryID']);
}
```

In the SearchModel:

public function search($params)
{
    $query = TabCve::find();

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['strNumber' => 'DESC']],
]);

$query->select(["intCveID","strNumber","fltScore","strDescription","datImported","intCvePhaseID","intCveTypeID",'progress.intProgressCategoryID']);
$query->joinWith("phase");
$query->joinWith("type");
$query->joinWith("progress");
$query->Where(['not like', 'strDescription', '** RESERVED **%', false]);
$query->andWhere(['not like', 'strDescription', '** REJECT **%', false]);
//$query->andWhere(["intProgressID" => null]);

$this->load($params);

if (!$this->validate()) {
    // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
    // $query->where('0=1');
    return $dataProvider;
}

$query->andFilterWhere([
    'intCveID' => $this->intCveID,
    'fltScore' => $this->fltScore,
    'datImported' => $this->datImported,
]);

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'strNumber', $this->strNumber])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'strDescription', $this->strDescription])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','tabPhase.strPhase', $this->intCvePhaseID])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','datImported',$this->datImported])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','tabType.strType', $this->intCveTypeID])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like','tabProgress.tabCategory.strCategory', $this->intCveTypeID])
    ;
return $dataProvider;
}
```

How do I have to implement the fields in these lines:

```
$query->select(["intCveID","strNumber","fltScore","strDescription","datImported","intCvePhaseID","intCveTypeID",'progress.intProgressCategoryID']);
```

and:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like','tabProgress.tabCategory.strCategory', $this->intCveTypeID])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your seachModel you need public var for filter ..

not need select because this are provide by find.. and is better rearrange the code below

```
$query->select(["intCveID","strNumber","fltScore","strDescription","datImported","intCvePhaseID","intCveTypeID",'progress.intProgressCategoryID']);
$query->joinWith("phase");
$query->joinWith("type");
$query->joinWith("progress");
$query->Where(['not like', 'strDescription', '** RESERVED **%', false]);
$query->andWhere(['not like', 'strDescription', '** REJECT **%', false]);
```

in another way like suggested in this doc

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

For

> ```
> ->andFilterWhere(['like','tabProgress.tabCategory.strCategory', 
>         $this->intCveTypeID])
> ```

the samples provide in the link above suggest the  use of getter for retrieve the column you need and the use of this getter also in andFilterWhere

this way :

in your Model  you already have  a

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TabCategory::className(),
     ['intCategoryID' =>   'intProgressCategoryID']);
}
```

then you can buil a getter for   for strCategory

```
public function getStr_category() {
    return $this->category->strCategory;
}
```

at this point you can retrieve the data in you modelSearch with

```
->andFilterWhere(['like','str_category', $this->intCveTypeID])
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And what should i put in here:
`->andFilterWhere(['like','tabProgress.tabCategory.strCategory', $this->intCveTypeID])`
Because this approach is not working.

Answer (score 0):

visit a complete tutorial about this question in :

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/851/yii2-gridview-sorting-and-searching-with-a-junction-table-column-many-to-many-relationship/

according to this tutorial you should : 
1. set your related table attribute as public in search model like this :

```
public $groupname;
```

2 .  include attribute in the rules :

```
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['id', 'gender', 'status', 'sentstatus'], 'integer'],
            [['groupname', 'addeddate', 'updateddate'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
```

3. change default query to following code in function `search()` in search model :

   ```
   public function search($params) {
   $query = Contacts::find()->innerJoinWith('groups', true);
   ```
4. and in andfilterwhere add wanted attribute  . like this :

   ```
   $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'firstname', $this->firstname])
                  ... 
                   ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'groupname', $this->groupname]);
   ```

in your **view** class and in Gridview your wanted column should like this :

```
'columns' => [
                ...
            [
                'attribute' => 'tags',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    $groups= '';
                    foreach ($data->groups as $group) {
                        $groups .= '<a href="/group/' . $group->id . '">' .
                        $group->group_name . '</a> | ';
                    }
                    return $groups;
         },
        'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(group::find()->asArray()->all(), 'group_name','group_name'),
                ],
```

*and if table relation is `hasOne()` you should read this tutorial :*

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)