# yii2 sort gridview on function column

Tags: sorting, gridview, yii2

I have a grid view i am populating with a data provider that gets its data from an active query. One of my columns is displayed via a function in the view that evaluates data from 2 different tables and displays one or the other value (based on date) i would like to be able to sort this column, but because its not part of the original SQL statement the ORDER BY clause created by the sort widget is not aware of the column to sort on. My question is, is there a way to sort the data after it has been passed and loaded into the grid view, or is there a better way to gather the data retrieved from the function so that it can be sorted.

```
[
  'label'=>'Last Backup Date',
  'value'=>function($data)
{
  if(!is_null($data->backupEvent) && !is_null($data->backups))
{
  return MAX($data->backupEvent->eventTime,$data->backups->fieldValue);
}elseif(!is_null($data->backupEvent))
{
  return $data->backupEvent->eventTime;
}elseif(!is_null($data->backups)) {
  return $data->backups->fieldValue;
  }
 }
],
```

Comment: If the  value function can be easly combined with the dataProvider query the simplest way is extend the query or the dataProvider and add the related sort config .. you can see this SO for sample or suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509747/yii2-gridview-implement-filter-and-sort-for-values-for-related-table-of-foreign/35512032#35512032

Comment: the issue is i need to evaluate the 2 tables with some php code before returning a result. So i wont be able to code the function into the SQL statement.

Comment: The sorting for gridview in based on sorting provided by order by inSQL. so if you can build a proper related sql you can use sort othervwise .. i suggest you of seaching for order by array data provider and if you find somethings take example from  this